# Load Balancing to 2 apache virtual host in Linux

Tags: linux, webserver, load-balancing

based web server online and I am trying to set it up with a load balancing so my website will be up 24/7. Is this possible and what are the ways to do it if possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible.

The easiest/cheapest way for you to accomplish that is to do the load balancing from DNS. Therefore you need two public IP addresses which are both assigned for the same name in DNS.

When one of the server goes down you need to move the IP address of the server which is down to the one that still works.

Otherwise you would have to edit the DNS record.